# Getting hours between 2 dates

Tags: excel, excel-2010

```
A1 = 29/05/2015 14:07
B1 = 01/06/2015 16:02
C1 = =(B1-A1)*24
```

Why am I only getting `22:00` in `C1`?

I was expecting it to count all the hours on the weekend too...

Comment: btw: B1-A1 = 3d 01:55, (B1-A1)*24 = 73d 22:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either
A) adjust the formatting to number
or
B) do not multiply by 24 and simply adjust the formatting to `[h]:mm`